# Atmel Studio 7.0 Simulator and interrupts, while in disassemble mode

Tags: c, assembly, avr

I'm busy on a self-educating project using AVR Simulator of Atmel Studio software to emulate my code (my physical target is an Atmega328, on Arduino Uno R3 board).

I got repeatedly what appears to me, a wrong behaviour, when using « disassemble mode »  (whereas in native C Source debug mode, it is OK)

In normal simulator ("C")mode, everything going on straightforward, interrupt is called.

When running the same code using "disassembly" mode, interrupt routine is no more called...

My "sketche" is the following (inspired from some source i found on atmel docs, added the counter interrupt) :

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
    static int savePC = 0;

    savePC++;
}

int main (void)
{
    // setMode(PORTC, output)
    DDRC = 0xff;
    // setMode(PORTB, input)
    DDRB = 0x00;
    // timer_freq = clock_freq/8
    TCCR0B = 0x02;
    // enable timer0 COMP_A interrupt mask
    TIMSK0 = 0x02;
    // after 5*8 = 40 cycles
    OCR0A = 0x05;

    // enable interrupts mask
    sei();

    /* Insert application code here, after the board has been initialized. */
    while(1) {
        PORTC = PINB + 1;
    }
}
```

I also use this "stim" debug script (found in Atmel database alongside the base ASM sketche "C=B+1") :

```
// Example stimuli file, feeds any output on PINC back to PINB.
#10
$repeat 10
    PINB = *PINC
    #10
    $break
$endrep
```

Comment: how are you stepping through the code?  via 'next' or via 'step'?  You might want to open a 'watch' window for the 'savepc' variable to see if it is being incremented.  Note: 'PORTc' is the enabling/disabling of the pull up resisters, You probably do not want to be changing those from some random input value

Comment: shouldn't the interrupt handler function be clearing the appropriate 'interrupt pending' bit.

Comment: @user3629249 : I use step over (F10), inside disassembly view. Continue (F5) works, interrupt is called. What is "next" ? OCFOA bit of TIFR0 is cleared by MCU just before calling handler routine. PORTC is an output port because of DDRC = 0xFF; so there no pullup here :]

Comment: given this code: `c = a+b; myFunction(); a++;`  the concepts are: 1) `step into` which will enter the `myFunction()`   2) `step over` which will not stop until the `a++`l  3) `continue` which will run until the next break point or when program is exited.  For your case:  If using 'step into` then the debugger will stop in the interrupt function.    If using the 'step over` then the debugger will stop at the next line of instruction in the current source code

Comment: There is no function to enter. In disassembly mode I "step over" the ASM instruction generated by the while loop. There is no point to "step into" an ASM instruction.

Comment: In addition, i checked PC is incremented well. the problem there is no jump to ISR when interrupt flag is set, althrough global IF is set. PLEASE NOTE this is **specifically** when stepping in disassembly mode -- when stepping in source C code, everything works well.